# Some discrepancies in WordNet symmetric relations

Tags: lexical-semantics

I have extracted the number of each relation in WordNet as you can see below. Some relations, such as hypernym and hyponym, are not in the same size. What is wrong with it?

```
"count(*)"  "link"
"89172" "hypernym" ??
"89151" "hyponym"  ??
"21434" "similar"
"12288" "member holonym"
"12288" "member meronym"
"9111"  "part meronym" ??
"9104"  "part holonym" ??
"8589"  "instance hypernym"
"8589"  "instance hyponym"
"6676"  "domain category"
"6676"  "domain member category"
"2697"  "also"
"1742"  "verb group"
"1341"  "domain region"
"1341"  "domain member region"
"1277"  "attribute"
"970"   "domain usage"
"970"   "domain member usage"
"797"   "substance holonym"
"797"   "substance meronym"
"408"   "entail"
"221"   "cause"
```

the number are extracted by following query on MySQL version of Wordnet:

```
select  count(*),link from semlinks join linktypes using(linkid) group by linkid
```

Comment: Can you create an SQL query that lists those hypernyms that are described in WordNet as having a specific hyponym, and where they hyponym does not have the corresponding entry or the hypernym (and the other way around)? This might help you (or others here) tell whether there is some principled reason for this, or whether the missing entries were omitted by mistake.